# How can I tell whether a mathematics journal seems reputable?

Tags: journals, mathematics, disreputable-publishers

There are some general questions on this site about judging the reputability of journals in general:

- [How do you judge the quality of a journal?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/101/how-do-you-judge-the-quality-of-a-journal) and
- [How to identify predatory publishers/journals](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2158/how-to-identify-predatory-publishers-journals)

I am interested in answers specific to mathematics, that may not have been raised in the other questions.

I received the following email from the "American Journal of Pure and Applied Mathematics" ten days after submitting a paper online. How can I tell whether this is a reputable journal? In general, how can I tell whether a mathematics journal is reputable?

> Dear Authors,
>
> On behalf of the Chief Editor of the “American Journal of Pure and Applied Mathematics” we are happy to inform you that your article entitled ‘A possible approach proof to proof the Riemann Hypothesis” is accepted for publication in (Jan-June 2015).
>
> Please send DD/Cheque for US $ 250.00 payable to ‘ Vijay Kumar Jha ‘ to our address.
>
> Our address:
>   Vijay Kumar Jha
>   Managing Editor
>   c\o. ACADEMIC RESEARCH JOURNALS (INDIA)
>
> 4383/4A, Ansari Road, Darya Ganj, New Delhi-110002
>
> (M) 08826561892
>
> We thank you very much for your contribution and encourage you to continue submitting your future.
>
> Yours sincerely,

Comment: If I can ask, what led you to submit a paper to this journal?

Comment: i seeked in web for " journal of pure and applied mathematics " then i find a list of journal then it's appeared to me submission online instruction in large table has , name and .. and abstracact and .., then i'm doing all those insructions of submitting paper

Comment: The title of your paper is not too convincing.

Comment: the title of my paper is identical that in my paper

Comment: this is the title of my paper" A possible approach proof to proof The Riemann Hypothesis"

Comment: @user51189: I don't think the journal is likely to be of any quality. You can pay them for publication, but the result is not likely to help make the paper any more accepted in the community.

Comment: then , why they informed me that my paper is accepted for publication , in which sides ?

Comment: @user51189: if the journal has low standards, they may accept every paper that is submitted. In fact, a 10-day wait for review of a math paper is almost humorously short, and suggests that the paper was not sent out to an independent reviewer. We should not keep using these comments for back and forth conversations, though.

Comment: In case the question does not get reopened soon, here is one easy tip: **There are very few, if any, reputable math journals which require the author to pay for publication.  Thus -- in mathematics -- if a journal asks you to pay, it is very likely that they are predatory.**

Comment: @ff524: I think that perhaps "what makes a *math* journal reputable" is slightly different than "what makes a general journal reputable". For example, an answer here can talk about specific databases (MathSciNet and ZentrallBlatt MATH), and specific practices in mathematics which may not be applicable to other fields. In fact, I was writing such an answer when the question was closed...

Comment: I agree with Oswald Veblen: the OP asked about math journals, and this has not been asked before.  I gave in my comment above what I think is a good tip for math journals.  In many of the sciences, this tip would be ridiculously off.  More fundamentally: I see many amateur mathematicians being taken advantage of by predatory journals.  Evidently the issue of telling whether a journal is predatory is a complicated one, worth more than two questions on the site.

Comment: I'll leave it to Pete and Oswald to answer the revised question, but, in view of the danger that user51189 might send in $250, let me just say that I did some basic googling, and it did not inspire confidence in this journal.

Comment: For reference, this was previously asked at http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1041688/18398, and I asked the OP to ask it here, instead.

Comment: An immediate cause of suspicion is that something calling itself the **American** Journal of Pure and Applied Mathematics has a postal address in **India**.

Comment: Another immediate cause of suspicion that the article processing charge is payable by a cheque *made out in an individual's name*. Does "Academic Research Journals" not have a company bank account?

Comment: @Artie Prendergast-Smith : I think yes, now am ready to withdraw my paper from this journal

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For academic mathematicians, it's not so hard to avoid predatory journals. We have a sense of the journals that we "typically" publish in, and the journals we "aspire" to publish in, and we stick mostly to these journals. For journals we don't know yet, we can ask colleagues to get their opinion. One (possibly unfortunate) goal of publishing in academia is to build a vita and maintain/advance your career, and it doesn't help as much to publish in a journal that none of your colleagues or supervisors has heard about.

For people who don't have that kind of professional experience, there are several easier questions you can ask. The better answer to each of these is "Yes".  **On their own, none of these questions indicates that a journal is necessarily reputable or nonreputable.** But, if the journal gets a "No" answer to many of them, then I would be very hesitant to submit a paper.

- Does the journal publish with no cost to the author? Reputable mathematics journals almost never charge fees for publication. Some very good journals offer an open-access model as an option, but it is almost never the default at the moment.
- Is the journal indexed by MathSciNet and/or Zentralblatt MATH? These sites aim to be very comprehensive for mathematics journals. Being indexed is not really a sign of quality, but not being indexed is a red flag.
- Is the journal ranked on the [Australian Mathematical Society Ranking](http://www.austms.org.au/Rankings/AustMS_final_ranked.html)? Even C-rated journals can be OK, but if a journal is completely omitted I would take that as a reason to be cautious.
- Is the journal either published by a well-known publisher, or affiliated with a university or mathematical society?  Most reputable math journals fall into these categories, but not all. Some journals run by professional publishers are still not very reputable, of course.
- Does the journal have a professional looking website?  Grammatical errors or parts of the website that seem to be entirely missing are a cause for concern.
- Does the journal have a long history of publication (say, at least 20 years)?  Most predatory journals are very young; most math journals are relatively old.

The "American Journal of Pure and Applied Mathematics" has a "No" answer to all of these questions. If they really did have a 10-day turn around between receiving a paper and accepting it, as described in comments, I am even more skeptical of the quality of the journal - that is an almost absurdly fast turn around time for a mathematics journal.  I would not pay them anything to publish a paper of mine, nor would I recommend it to anyone else.

Of course, you *can* publish in a predatory journal, just as you *can* publish in a for-hire press. But if you are an amateur or "outsider" looking to publish in a math journal, you are likely doing it to get a sort of "seal of approval" on your paper. Journals that mathematicians view as unreputable will not give your paper that kind of recognition among mathematicians, just as degrees from unreputable colleges are unlikely to impress others.

If your goal is just to disseminate your mathematical work, and you don't require peer review, you can often use arXiv.org instead. Depending on the area, you may need to have a professional "sponsor", but the arXiv will keep your paper available for free for the indefinite future in a way that is widely accessible to the public.

Comment: Another way that academics (not just mathematicians) figure out which journals are reputable is by noticing which journals publish the papers that they cite, and which journals publish the papers that those papers cite, and so on.

Comment: @Oswald Veblen , I would be interest to make my paper in arxiv.org, but already request for me "endorser" , as i don't have any publication before

Comment: Thank you for your answer : pleas this is the journal that i submitted my work in it :http://www.academicresearchjournals.com/journal-detail.php?journals_id=37, you will find online submission

Comment: @user51189.....Journal seems like online shopping site to me.

Answer (score 6):

The publisher of this particular journal, "Academic Research Journals", appears on a widely cited list of "predatory publishers" who publish open access journals with very low standards and charge authors to publish.  You probably don't want a publication in this journal.

See Beall's list at:

http://scholarlyoa.com/publishers/

Also follow the link from the list to the criteria that Beall used to compile the list.  New predatory publishers pop up every week, so you really need to consider these issues in evaluating a new journal.

As ff524 has pointed out in the comments, there are actually two web sites using the name "Academic Research Journals"  The web site of academicresearchjournals.com could easily be confused with the other academicresearchjournals.org.  Whoever put together the .com web site used "Academic Research Journals (India)" rather than "Academic Research Journals" in some places but not others.  This certainly looks like a copycat operation.

In any case, the journal mentioned by the original poster has the appearance of one of these predatory journals and should be avoided for that reason.

Comment: The one linked on Beall's list is actually a *different* "Academic Research Journals" (based in Nigeria). This one is "Academic Research Journals (INDIA)" which is a different publisher (different websites and everything).

Comment: The web page of the journal still reads "Published by Academic Research Journals"  I guess it was too much work to change the name everywhere :-)

Comment: So it does, but this is still an inaccurate answer. I suggest you edit it.