# What are the differences between Peer Reviewed Journals and Refereed Journals?

Tags: publications, journals, peer-review, paper-submission, terminology

I would be interested to know the differences between peer reviewed journals and refereed journals in these aspects:

1. Conditions for the acceptance of papers for publications.
2. The time length of paper stage after submission.
3. Amount payable by authors.

Comment: They mean the exact same thing.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To expand on Yuichiro Fujiwara's comment, "peer review" and "refereeing" are exact synonyms, and no differences at all are implied by the names.  For historical reasons, some fields are more likely to use one term than the other (for example, mathematicians talk more often about refereeing than peer review).  Publishing practices also differ between fields in other ways, such as the length of the reviewing process.  There might be a weak correlation with the use of terms like peer review and refereeing, since both issues are heavily influenced by which field you are looking at.  However, I'd bet that any correlations are small, and in any case this is not a productive way to investigate journal differences (since knowing the field would tell you enormously more than just knowing which term the journal uses for peer review).

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, pleas look this answer  :Dear Rafik
Academic Research Journals are Peer Reviewed Journals. It is not a Refreed Journal.
It is not a Spam. So don't afraid to publish in this Journal. It is a developing Journal. So the amount is costlier.
So if you send money you can get Journal Copy. Nothing to Worry.
If you have any other doubts please feel free to share.
Are you a Doctorate in Mathematics?
Please reply me. i will give some other oppertunities.
With Regards
Dr.S.Lakshmi

Comment: this message directed to me from editor in chief .

Comment: @user51189 when an editor-in-chief sends you a semi-literate email like that, go somewhere else. And when a publisher is on [Beall's list of predatory publishers](http://scholarlyoa.com/publishers/), as "Academic Research Journals" is, go somewhere else.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers that's actually a [different "Academic Research Journals"](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/32394/how-can-i-tell-whether-a-mathematics-journal-seems-reputable/32400#comment72350_32400) from the one the OP is referring to.

Comment: @user51189 Dr. S. Lakshmi is the Nigerian prince of academic publishing.

Comment: @Energynumber : pleas check this link "online submission and pleas tel me if it's a predatory publishers :http://academicresearchjournals.com/journal-detail.php?journals_id=37,

Comment: @ Davidmh : he is found in editoriel boared as editor in chief of this journal:http://academicresearchjournals.com/journal-detail.php?journals_id=37,

Comment: @user51189 Any journal that publishes [this rubbish](http://academicresearchjournals.com/serialjournalmanager/pdf/1344853245.pdf) and claims to be high quality and peer-reviewed is, well... neither of those things to put it kindly. Ask your advisor if you're trying to decide where to publish, and stick to the popular and well-reputed journals in your field. It's usually pretty easy to spot predatory journals just by reading a few papers of the "research" they publish.

Comment: @user51189 That email made my day.

Comment: @Moriarty: Oh, that one's not so bad.  How about [this gem](http://academicresearchjournals.com/serialjournalmanager/pdf/1354275559.pdf) from one of its sister journals, in which it is proved that it is possible, given only the length of one side of a right triangle, to determine the lengths of the other two sides?

Answer (score 2):

I could be mistaken, but the correlation that I believed to exist was that refereeing was common in fields where works where fully self contained. E.g. with mathematics you do not need to additional research to (in)validate a work, as long as the steps are correct the conclusion is correct. Contrast this to a field like medicine where you would need to redo all the experiments as well to truly 'referee' a result, whilst peer review 'simply' means somebody went over your work and gauged it's reliability.

Now, I could well be mistaken and it's *definitely* not a clear cut line, but that seemed to be the general trend I observed. Then again, I don't know that great a number of fields that use the term 'refereed' over 'peer-reviewed' in the first place, so I could well be mistaken.