# Finding appropriate journal for submitting a modest paper in mathematics

Tags: publications, journals, mathematics, paper-submission

I've finished master studies in mathematics. Now I'm working on some papers, but I'm not so familiar with journals. I've submitted papers in some journals with impact factor, but it was rejected, while some other journals accept them (I doubt they accept anything for money).
My question is: how can I find an appropriate journal for a modest paper?

Comment: I would suggest first identifying the Journals that you have read where (a) the subject matter is similar, and (b) which publishes modest advancements to your field.

Comment: The Australian Mathematical Society [journal rankings](http://www.austms.org.au/Rankings/AustMS_final_ranked.html) might be useful.  You could try submitting to a journal with a rating of 'B', for instance.

Comment: While ranking might tell you how selective a journal is, it is far less useful in identifying a journal that closeness of topic match.

Comment: Beware of predatory journals. Here's the famous Beall's list: 
http://scholarlyoa.com/publishers/
http://scholarlyoa.com/individual-journals/

Also read about this: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCIgen
It's very funny and will show you how far these journals go just to get your money.

Comment: I would not try to do this without reading the paper.  Consider the journals that you cite frequently in the paper.  I recommend picking the journal before you start writing to ensure the paper is written to fit the journal.

Comment: That is the main reason I posted this question @Formagella.

Comment: I see some of you are miss-understanding the question. I'm not asking about finding a journal to fit my subject. I'm asking how to be aware of fake journals as well as finding journals compatible to some basic standards for publishing a paper (not so qualitative journal, but also not one which accepts anything for money).

Comment: @Emin: The question in your last post makes sense. I think it has been answered already here: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/32394/how-can-i-tell-whether-a-mathematics-journal-seems-reputable/32403#32403